# Compiled samba from source upgrade - version mismatch

Tags: samba, samba4

I'm testing Samba 4 AD (test environment) on CentOS 8. First attemp was with version 4.13.5 without cups support because I have installed packages listed in section "Manually maintained Distribution-specific Package lists" in this link https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Package_Dependencies_Required_to_Build_Samba. I was my mistake but after manually installed packages it was succesful.

Few hours later I realized that I forgot cups support so I have installed cups-devel + other packages and run `./configure && make && make install` again. Everything seems ok and domain is still working.

Yesterday I have tried upgrade to 4.14.2 but this time I saw section "Verified Package Dependencies" https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Package_Dependencies_Required_to_Build_Samba and install all packages from git.samba.org link (except git package) before running `./configure && make && make install`

Today I was trying to disable password complexity for Windows users. I was unsuccesful with GPO but found this link: https://serverfault.com/a/780966. In nutshell that user said that it is not possible to change password complexity with GPO with Samba AD and said he was succesful with this command:

```
samba-tool domain passwordsettings set --complexity=off
```

But I got error about Samba different version:

```
[root@ad1 ~]# /usr/local/samba/bin/samba-tool domain passwordsettings set --complexity=off
ERROR(<class 'ImportError'>): uncaught exception - /usr/local/samba/lib/private/libcliauth-samba4.so: version `SAMBA_4.13.5' not found (required by /usr/local/samba/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/samba/samba3/libsmb_samba_internal.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
  File "/usr/local/samba/bin/samba-tool", line 45, in <module>
    retval = cmd._run("samba-tool", subcommand, *args)
  File "/usr/local/samba/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/samba/netcmd/__init__.py", line 235, in _run
    return self.subcommands[subcommand]._run(
  File "/usr/local/samba/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/samba/netcmd/main.py", line 36, in __getitem__
    fromlist=['cmd_%s' % attr]),
  File "/usr/local/samba/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/samba/netcmd/domain.py", line 44, in <module>
    import samba.ntacls
  File "/usr/local/samba/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/samba/ntacls.py", line 35, in <module>
    from samba.samba3 import libsmb_samba_internal as libsmb
```

Some package is still refering to version 4.13.5 insted new 4.14.2. What I did wrong during the update? Thank you

**UPDATE**:
Because it is test environment I have tried this:

```
1. Stop samba ad dc
2. Backup /usr/local/samba
3. Delete /usr/local/samba/bin, lib, lib64, libexec and sbin
4. cd to source samba-4.14.2 and make install
5. Start samba ad dc + DB check
```

Now there is no problem with link to old version. So did I anything wrong during 4.13.5 -> 4.14.2 or there was some orphant link to old compiled version (samba bug)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the correct fix or not, but I had a similar problem after compiling and installing Samba 4.14.7.

Quite by accident I managed to delete /usr/local/samba/lib64/python3.6.

To repair it I did:

1. Stop Samba4
2. Re-run 'make install' for samba-4.14.7
3. Re-start samba

samba-tool works again!

Hope that helps....